# Como fazer uma requisição enviando dados de cookies?

Tags: python, cookies

Quero fazer uma requisição `GET` para uma determinada URL, mas quero enviar dados de cookies, como faz um navegador web.

Por exemplo, no código abaixo:

```py
from urllib import request
req = request.Request('http://servidor/pagina.html')
response = request.urlopen(req)
print(response.read().decode())
```

Se eu imprimir os cabeçalhos, o resultado é uma lista vazia:

```py
print(req.header_items())
```

Mas eu quero enviar um header `HTTP` como este:

```py
Cookie: atributo=valor+do+atributo
```

---

Parte da pergunta para quem já é experiente com Python:

> Estou no [Nível 17](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/return/romance.html) do pythonchallenge.com e preciso fazer uma requisição enviando um cookie "info" com o valor "the+flowers+are+on+their+way" para a url http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/stuff/violin.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver parcialmente a questão com o método `add_header` do objeto `request`.

```py
from urllib import request
req = request.Request('http://servidor/pagina.html')

req.add_header('Cookie', 'atributo=valor+do+atributo')

response = request.urlopen(req)
print(response.read().decode())
```

O problema é que dessa forma eu tenho que fazer o *encode* dos atributos do cookie manualmente.

Não consegui resolver a questão com um objeto `Cookie`:

```py
from http import cookiejar
cookie = cookiejar.Cookie(1, 'atributo', 'valor do atributo',
                          80, True, 'www.servidor.com', True, True,
                          '/', True, False, -1, False, None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nunca programei Python, mas olhando nos [docs.python-requests.org](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) acho que você pode fazer assim:

```
url = 'http://servidor/pagina.html'
cookies = dict(info='the+flowers+are+on+their+way')

req = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
req.text  # '{"cookies": {"info": "the+flowers+are+on+their+way"}}'
```

Comment: Maicon, realmente esta pode ser uma solução. Mas essa biblioteca não vem com o Python e neste momento eu queria evitar o uso e instalação de bibliotecas externas. Abraço.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelo aviso.